# How to deal with html excerpt?

Tags: php, html

It introduced a lot of non-closed tags like below:

```
<div>
<table>...</table>
```

The `</div>` is truncated by code like this:

```
(strlen($row['body']) > 200 ? substr($row['body'],0,200) . '...' : $row['body'])
```

And the layout of the whole page is broken,how to deal with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that `$row['body']` contains HTML that you want to truncate to 200 visible characters:

**Strip out HTML Tags**

This is the quickest fix but may not be what you want:

```
$body= strip_tags($row['body']);
echo(strlen($body) > 200 ? substr($body,0,200) . '...' : $body);
```

**Parse HTML and truncate text**

Using PHP's [DOMDocument](http://us.php.net/DomDocument) class you can parse the HTML, check the length of text within HTML tags, count the length of text in the content, and remove any tags after the character limit from the HTML contained in `$row['body']` while retaining well-formed HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to create a post preview or excerpt that contains valid HTML. It parses the HTML using PHP's DOMDocument as leepowers suggested:

http://bizzybytes.com/html-excerpt-php

Comment: This would be better if the length check was checking how long the text content is, excluding the html tags themselves.

Comment: Agreed! But as somebody way smarter than me once said, "over optimization is the root of all evil". Its simpler to just increase $num_chars to accommodate more actual text (minus the html). Another variable and the use of $node->textContent will get you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have left it out for brevity but I see no  tags

it should be

```
<div>
<table><tr><td>...</td></tr></table>
```

Also use the following you may have html embedded in your $row['body']

```
(strlen($row['body']) > 200 ? substr($row['body'],0,200) . '...' : htmlspecialchars($row['body']))
```

DC